# Chrome using incorrect local IP Address

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, ip-address, iis-express

Doing local development on my IIS machine, I was previously using a static local ip of `192.168.0.100:542`. I recently had to factory reset my router and now I have `192.168.1.x`. I can access the local site using `localhost:542`, but some AJAX requests and redirects are still being made to the old IP address.

I've tried clearing cache, clearing Chrome's DNS cache, doing `ipconfig /flushdns`, and using an incognito window but it's still happening.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is because I had the old IP Address still set as my `APP_URL` in `.env` (Laravel).